# data.table equivalent of group_by() %>% mutate(across())

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

what is `data.table`'s equivalent of `dplyr`'s

`mtcars %>% group_by(vs) %>% mutate(across(mpg:qsec, ~ .x/sum(.x)))`

this gives a different result than

`mtcars[, lapply(.SD, function(x) { x/sum(x) }), .SDcols = mpg:qsec, by = vs]`

in particular, the latter drops the other columns (`am`, `gear`, and `carb`) while the former does not

it is possible to do the following

`mtcars[, c(lapply(.SD, function(x) { x/sum(x) }), .(am = am, gear = gear, carb = carb)), .SDcols = mpg:qsec, by = vs]`

but this is unsatisfactory as i have to spell out each other column, and impractical in the case where there a large number of such columns

Comment: Lazy uninformed option: `library(dtplyr); mtcars %>%  lazy_dt() %>% group_by(vs) %>% mutate(across(mpg:qsec, ~ .x/sum(.x)))` to translate (sometimes inefficiently) your dplyr query to data.table. Add `%>% show_query()` to see the translated syntax. Doesn't translate the "across" part but rather translates what across does, ie creates the calculation across the impacted columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible way to solve your problem.

```
library(data.table)

dt = as.data.table(mtcars)

cols = names(dt[,mpg:qsec])

dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/sum(x)), by=vs, .SDcols=cols]

dt

          mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
         <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
 1: 0.07021063 0.04477612 0.02893990 0.03221083 0.06387160 0.03946140 0.05477720     0     1     4     4
 2: 0.07021063 0.04477612 0.02893990 0.03221083 0.06387160 0.04330211 0.05664082     0     1     4     4
 3: 0.06631763 0.06250000 0.05823986 0.07271306 0.07125671 0.06346080 0.06875531     1     1     4     1
...
```

if you don't want to modify your original data, then copy it

```
dt2 = copy(dt)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/sum(x)), by=vs, .SDcols=cols]
```